# Write a list to a cell in Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, list, xlsxwriter

I would like to write a list of lists : `k = [['1','a'],['2','b'],['3','c']]` - to a cell in a Python excel sheet.

My code:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('names.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A1', 'Generic Name')
```

I have tried:
`worksheet.write_row('B1', allmajor)`
which causes the contents the list `k` to be written in separate cells (B1, C1, D1..).

Doing: `worksheet.write('B1', ','.join(k))` causes the cotnents of cell B1 to have strings like - `'1','a','2','b','3','c'`

Is there any way in which I can write a list to a cell such that cell B1 looks like `[['1','a'],['2','b'],['3','c']]`? Is there any other module in Python that can facilitate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) which gives a string representation of the list object:

```
worksheet.write('B1', repr(k))
```

At python prompt you can see how it works:

```
>>> k = [['1','a'],['2','b'],['3','c']]
>>> k
[['1', 'a'], ['2', 'b'], ['3', 'c']]
>>> repr(k)
"[['1', 'a'], ['2', 'b'], ['3', 'c']]"
>>> print(repr(k))
[['1', 'a'], ['2', 'b'], ['3', 'c']]
```

In the case of your simple list structure, you could just cast it to a string as well like `str(k)` but repr is probably better for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can take care of this by converting your list of list to string. For example

```
>>import pandas as pd
>>list1=[['1','a'],['2','b'],['3','c']]
>>list2=[['4','a'],['5','b'],['6','c']]
>>df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[str(list1), str(list2)]]})
```

Now when you save it in a comma separated format,each element will be treated as a string. When you read this back from file, you can use `ast` to convert it back into a list of lists.

```
>>import ast
>>[ast.literal_eval(i) for i in df['a']]
```

Hope this answers your question.